# Adding classes from src/test/kotlin to Corda MockNetwork nodes as a Cordapp

Tags: corda

Sometimes, in our Cordapp test code, we need to inject additional classes (be they additional flows, Corda services etc) as a Cordapp. Previously in Corda 3.x this was possible. It doesn't appear to be the case in Corda 4.x.

Example:

Given the kotlin template assume there is an additional class in the test sources for

```
/**
 * This service is representative of a service we use in our primary project.
 * It contains logic that's very useful from the perspective of our cordapps testing.
 * Historically in Corda 3.x we could load this service into the MockNetwork node's classpath
 * This is no longer the case. The log line in the initialiser is never called.
 */
@CordaService
class TestCordaService(serviceHub: AppServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
//...
}
```

In Corda 3.x we could startup the network as follows:

```
MockNetwork(cordappPackages = listOf("<package names>"))
```

Is there a way of achieving this in Corda 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation I came across the class `net.corda.testing.node.internal.CustomCordapp`.

We can use this class like this:

```
  // we collect the distinct set of paths in the event that we don't add the same cordapp twice
  private val cordapps = listOf(
    TemplateContract::class,
    Initiator::class
// and other key cordapp classes
  ).map { it.packageName }.distinct().map { TestCordapp.findCordapp(it) }

// here we declare a custom cordapp based the entry-point classes in a given test package
  private val customTestCordapp = CustomCordapp(packages = setOf(TestCordaService::class.packageName),
    classes = setOf(TestCordaService::class.java))

  private val network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(cordappsForAllNodes = cordapps + customTestCordapp))
  // ...
```

See this repo for an example: https://github.com/dazraf/mock-network-service-reproducer